# JavaScript (grunt): regular expressions for path to a file

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs

I'm working with `gruntfile.js` and I'm trying to create regular expression for path to files, for example:

```
.settings/.file1

directory/.settings/file.js

dir-001/.settings/subdir/.file2

dir/org.com.pack/.file3
```

My latest solution: `**/*`

But it's not correct, all files & folders that include `'.'` just ignored.
I have no idea how to resolve this.

Please, help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gruntfile.js is using node-glob syntax, see the [docs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#dots) about `.` files.
So you can use :

```
  ['**/*', '.*/**/*', '**/.*', '**/.*/**/*']
```

Or use the configuration `dot:true` (but I don't know where to put it in the Gruntfile.js)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution about dot config! This is works for me =)

Comment: You're welcome, you can upvote/accept my answer since it works for you. :-) Enjoy Grunt !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
.*(\/\.?){0,}.+
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/bM3gO0/1)